# How does one convert ARRAY_TO_STRING and ARRAY_AGG into arel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an Arel statement that looks like the following:

```
vulns.project(vulns[:id],
              vulns[:cve_id],
              vulns[:severity],
              vulns[:published_on],
              vulns[:description],
  "ARRAY_TO_STRING((ARRAY_AGG(#{releases[:version]} ORDER BY #{releases[:released_on]} DESC))[1:10], ', ')")
  .join(releases_vulns)
    .on(releases_vulns[:vulnerability_id].eq(vulns[:id]))
```

The toughest part that I am running into is the `array_agg` and `array_to_string`. I've checked arel documentation and I did not see a particular matching method to work out a query like this. Has anyone encountered this problem? I could use some help. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to convert it is the following:

```
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new 'array_agg', [expression goes here]
Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new 'array_to_string', [array_input, Arel::Nodes::Quoted.new(',')]
```

Comment: Could you give an example of using this please?